# A problem involving a Normal-Gamma distribution

Tags: self-study, bayesian, normal-distribution, gamma-distribution

Would someone mind telling me if my working for the following problem looks reasonable?

> An astrophysicist studying the expansion of the universe has a set of redshift measurements, each covering the same section of the Milky Way. If current theory is correct, redshift should be close to zero.
>
> (i) Let $x_i$ be the $i$-th observation and assume $x_i\sim\text{N}(x_i|\mu,1/\lambda),\;i=1,\dots,n$. Write down the joint posterior distribution of $(\mu,\lambda)$ using the conjugate prior, $$\pi(\mu,\lambda)\sim\text{NG}\left(\mu\left|m,\frac{1}{p\lambda}\right.\right)\text{Ga}(\lambda|a,b),$$ where $m\in\mathbb{R}$ and $p,a,b>0$ are known constants, and give explicit expressions for its parameters.
>
> (ii) The scientist may report a discrepancy (call this decision $d_1$) or an agreement (decision $d_2$) with the current theory supported by the data. If a real discrepancy is reported there is a good chance it would be published in a top journal; if the discrepancy is not real, her career would suffer a major drawback. After some consideration, she believes that the following loss function reflects well her preferences: $$L(d_1,\mu)=\begin{cases}10 & |\mu|\leq0.01,\\ 0&|\mu|>0.01,\end{cases}\hspace{2em}L(d_2,\mu)=\begin{cases}0 & |\mu|\leq0.01,\\ 3&|\mu|>0.01.\end{cases}$$ A set of $n=250$ measures are taken and the following statistics are recorded: $$\bar{x}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=0.02,\hspace{2em}s_d^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2=1/4.$$ After elicitation, the scientist’s prior parameters are $$m=0,\;p=0.01,\;a=2,\; b=0.6.$$ Should the scientist report a discrepancy?
>
> [HINT: If $T\sim t_{254}$, then $\mathbb{P}[T\leq0.316]=0.624$, $\mathbb{P}[T\leq0.675]=0.75$, $\mathbb{P}[T\leq0.947]=0.828$, $\mathbb{P}[T\leq1.651]=0.95$].

By my working, $$\pi(\mu,\lambda|\textbf{x})=\text{NG}(\mu,\lambda|m^\ast,p^\ast,a^\ast,b^\ast),$$ where \begin{align}p^\ast&=p+n=250.01,\\ m^\ast&=\frac{pm+n\bar{x}}{p^\ast}=0.02,\\ a^\ast&=a+\frac{n}{2}=127,\\ b^\ast&=b+\frac{n}{2}\left(s^2+\frac{p}{p^\ast}(\bar{x}-m)^2\right)\approx31.85\end{align}
and
$$ \pi(\mu|\textbf{x}) = \int_\Lambda\pi(\mu,\lambda|\textbf{x})\text{ d}\lambda = \text{St}\left(\mu\left|m,\frac{p^\ast a^\ast}{b^\ast},2a^\ast\right.\right)$$
so $$\sqrt{\frac{p^\ast a^\ast}{b^\ast}}(\mu-m)\approx31.6\mu\sim t_{2a^\ast}=t_{254}$$
so $$\mathbb{P}[\mu\leq0.01]=\mathbb{P}[31.6\mu\leq0.316]=0.624$$
so, by the symmetry of the $t$ distribution,
$$\mathbb{P}[|\mu|\leq0.01]=2\times(0.624-0.5)=0.248$$
so $$O_{1,2}=\frac{L(d_1,\mu)}{L(d_2,\mu)}=\frac{10\times0.248}{3\times(1-0.248)}\approx1.01\in(1,4)$$
so the result is not worth mentioning.